# windows server 2012 mysql log files deleted but free up space in c

Tags: mysql, windows, logging

I have deleted big mysql log files in windows server 2012 and clean it from recycle bin. However, I found the C drive space is not free up according to the deleted files. What is the deleted files gone. I have chose to permanent deleted it. However, space is not free up.

Comment: I restart the Mysql Server. Then the space is freed.

Comment: There's no question here. Tip, never fiddle with MySQL (or any databases' file directly). Especially while running with no recovery mechanism.  'set global expire_bin_log_days=1; `[FLUSH BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-binary-logs) would of been saner solution.